# How to handle a changed array allocated following the allocated array when using 'push'

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutability

I just found a strange thing when using 'push' in Javascript.

For example, the property 'thisPointArrs2' values of 'arrs' are all the same. I expected them to be different, as each point when I allocated 'thisPointArrs2' is different. Is this the 'immutable' thing? I don't know how to solve this hassle.

```
let arrs = [];
let arrs2 = [];

while(...){

  arrs2.push(...);
  arrs.push({ thisPointArrs2 : arrs2})

}
```

However, no problems with the function 'filter'. the property 'thisPointArrs2' values of 'arrs' differ as I intended.

```
let arrs = [];
let arrs2 = [];

while(...){

  arrs2 = arrs2.filter(...);
  arrs.push({ thisPointArrs2 : arrs2})

}
```

Comment: oh.. Object.assign or spread operator have solved the issue.

Comment: This behaviour is due to reference f objects. We need to clone objects before assigning or pushing those into other array or assigning to object.

Comment: In case they are just string or number or boolean types, wouldn't I need to consider reference?

Comment: In that case, you don't need reference. You can go into details here https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the first example and the second is, that `.push` changes the internals of the array (adding one) while `.filter` creates a new array (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)). Since arrays are not primitives, they are inserted by reference.

The spread operator takes all attributes of an object and put's them in a new object, that's why it solved your object. `Object.assign` is basically the same as spread.

I recommend [reading about references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), as it can be a bit confusing at first - but you wouldn't want to have it different once you learn how to deal with them.

Since you referenced the immutability tag, there are a bunch of libraries that prevent exactly this behaviour by making all objects immutable. Using one of these, you would get the results you expected - together with all the problems that can arise from that behaviour. The use-case is protecting data object against unintended changes. Well known libraries are [immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) or [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction). Note that this is probably an advanced topic and likely not useful/necessary for beginners.